# Ember.js next image

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Ok i'm new to ember.js 
Just followed some tutorials so far so good
But my question is how I can implement a next/back to image assuming the ids of images are random?
My app.js so far

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});



App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
  this.resource('posts');
  this.resource('post',{path:':post_id'})
});




App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return posts;
  }
});


App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return posts.findBy('id', params.post_id);
  }

});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like any of your code attempts to answer the question. What is the relationship between a post and an image?

Comment: in "posts" route there are "post" each containing an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but for starters you'll probably need to create a [Template](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/the-application-template/) (to hold the html), a [View](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/) (to manage user interactivity), and a [Controller](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/) (to manipulate/decorate model data) for each of your routes.

There is definitely more than one way you could implement a next/prev image feature. Below is an example of a very rudimentary approach. You could easily create something more visually appealing and responsive, but the following should point you in the right direction. The code below hasn't been tested; just giving you the concept and a starting point. You don't need to necessarily create Views at this point (generic ones will be created behind the scenes if none exist), but you'll probably want them if you want to do any animations or other DOM manipulation.

**Templates**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
{{#each}}
  <li>{{#link-to 'post' id}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</li>
{{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
<h1>{{title}}</h1> 
<img class="post-image" {{bind-attr src=imageSrc}}/>
<a href="#" {{action 'prevImage'}}>Prev Image</a> 
<a href="#" {{action 'nextImage'}}>Next Image</a>
</script>
```

**Controllers**

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});

/* This assumes the Post model contains an images field which is an array
 * post.images = [{src:'source_path 1'},{src:'source_path 2'},...] 
 */
App.PostController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  //holds current index into the images list
  currentImage: 0,

  //computed property which observes changes to currentImage
  imageSrc: function()
  {
    return this.get('images')[this.get('currentImage')].src;
  }.property('currentImage'),

  actions:
  {
    nextImage: function()
    {
      var next = this.get('currentImage') + 1;
      if( next >= this.get('images').length )
        next = 0;
      this.set('currentImage', next);
    },
    prevImage: function()
    {
      var prev = this.get('currentImage') - 1;
      if( prev <= -1 )
        prev = this.get('images').length-1;
      this.set('currentImage', prev);
    }
  }
});
```

**Views**

```
App.PostsView = Ember.View.extend({

});


App.PostView = Ember.View.extend({

});
```